# Leer una direccion de memoria almacenada en un archivo de texto

Tags: c++

Necesito leer la dirección de memoria de un puntero desde un archivo, ya implemente la función, una función de tipo entero que al leer el archivo 
me devuelve la dirección almacenada:

```
int Cargar(std::string nombre)
{
std::ifstream archivo; 

archivo.open(nombre.c_str(),std::ios::in);

if(!archivo)
{
    std::cout<<"No se pudo cargar el archivo."<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int direccion;

archivo>>std::hex>>direccion;

return direccion;

}

int main()
{
  int direccion = Cargar("Direcciones.txt");
  std::cout<<direccion<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Cuando imprimo por pantalla el resultado es siempre 0.

Nota: en el archivo "Direcciones.txt", solo se encuentra la siguiente linea:

```
0x60fe1c
```

Comment: En SO no debes añadir (SOLUCIONADO) al título de tu pregunta, lo que debes hacer es marcar como correcta a la pregunta que es la solución, y si ninguna de las pregunta lo es entonces publica una respuesta y marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualización: al final solo necesitaba utilizar `"std::hex"` para leer el archivo,aunque opcionalmente si por algún motivo necesitan convertir un string que almacena un valor hexadecimal a una variable de tipo entero, pueden utilizar `"std::stoi"` de la siguiente manera:

```
int entero = std::stoi(texto.c_str(),nullptr,16);
```

Con el tercer parámetro le estamos indicando que nos convierta el entero a base 16 (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 2):

Si tu intención es leer un número... ¿Por qué lees primero en un `char[]`? Te puedes ahorrar este paso y leer directamente en un entero:

```
int direccion;
archivo >> direccion;

std::cout << direccion << '\n';

return direccion;
```

Entre otras cosas, `stoi` **no convierte** de hexadecimal a base 10, luego si los valores están en este formato, el número leído va a ser **siempre** 0 (el primer dígito del número hexadecimal):

```
0x1234
 ^ la x ya no es un digito, deja de leer
^ Primer digito numerico
```

Comment: Al final lo resolví utilizando std::stoul.

Comment: @M1L0 Eso convierte a `unsigned long`... ten cuidado que los rangos de valores que admiten ambas variables son distintos y puedes tener problemas de desbordamiento

Comment: Es verdad, ya actualice la información y el código,gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo, que el problema esta en la conversión del char* en int. En C lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cargar(FILE* arch)
{
    int retorno;
    char buffer[500];
    rewind(arch);
    fgets(buffer, 500, arch);
    sscanf(buffer, "%x", &retorno);
    return retorno;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* arch = fopen("memory.txt", "rt");
    if(!arch) return 0;
    int retorno = cargar(arch);
    printf("El retorno es: %x", retorno);
    fclose(arch);
    return 0;
}
```

La salida por pantalla fue la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También te puede servir de información esta [FUENTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788790/storing-a-hexadecimal-number-in-an-int).

Comment: C no es C++, de la misma forma que la pirita no es oro... por fuera se pueden llegar a parecer, pero por dentro son completamente diferentes. Puedes tener código en C que no compile en C++ y viceversa. Tratar de encontrar la solución saltando de un lenguaje a otro no explica el motivo por el que el código original falla.